# Apple Id User's Info

Tags: rest, apple-id

Apple's JS Sign in implementation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms) seems to be returning User's Information in the following format:

```
{ "name": { "firstName": string, "lastName": string }, "email": string }
```

though the same flow through the REST API does not return the User's Info
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens

Is there anything that needs to be set explicitly in order to get the user info(first name and last name) from a rest API call?